# 'solve' syntax in MATLAB for symbolic nonlinear matrix equation

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation-solving

I have a symbolic matrix that depends on a complex parameter `q`. Let the matrix be `A(q)` and `b` a column vector. I would like to simultaneously solve the equations

`A*b==0; b'*b==1;`

using the [solve](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) command (preferably the numerical variant [vpasolve](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpasolve.html)). The variables to be found are both `b` and `q`. I am not quite sure about the syntax on how to do this and would appreciate any help on it. My main problem is that the equation is partially given in matrix form and the searched variable is a vector.

Do I have to resort to [fsolve](http://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) to achieve this? Or is there a way without defining a function?